# lubuntu how to enable wifi module

Tags: networking, lubuntu

```
lshw:
*-network DISABLED
                description: Wireless interface
                product: PRO/Wireless 3945ABG [Golan] Network 

Connection
                    vendor: Intel Corporation
                    physical id: 0
                    bus info: pci@0000:10:00.0
                    logical name: wlp16s0
                    version: 02
                    serial: 00:1c:bf:71:d0:08
                    width: 32 bits
                    clock: 33MHz
                    capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
                    configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwl3945 driverversion=5.0.0-32-generic firmware=N/A latency=0 link=no multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
                    resources: irq:27 memory:e4000000-e4000fff

lsmod: Module                  Size  Used by
bnep                   24576  2
i915                 1818624  2
arc4                   16384  2
iwl3945                73728  0
kvmgt                  28672  0
iwlegacy               94208  1 iwl3945
mac80211              819200  2 iwl3945,iwlegacy
vfio_mdev              16384  0
btusb                  49152  0
coretemp               20480  0
btrtl                  20480  1 btusb
mdev                   24576  2 kvmgt,vfio_mdev
snd_hda_codec_hdmi     53248  1
wmi_bmof               16384  0
hp_wmi                 16384  0
snd_hda_codec_analog    16384  1
btbcm                  16384  1 btusb
vfio_iommu_type1       28672  0
cfg80211              679936  3 iwl3945,iwlegacy,mac80211
snd_hda_codec_generic    77824  1 snd_hda_codec_analog
sparse_keymap          16384  1 hp_wmi
ledtrig_audio          16384  1 snd_hda_codec_generic
btintel                24576  1 btusb
vfio                   32768  3 kvmgt,vfio_mdev,vfio_iommu_type1
joydev                 28672  0
snd_hda_intel          49152  3
bluetooth             557056  26 btrtl,btintel,btbcm,bnep,btusb
kvm                   630784  1 kvmgt
irqbypass              16384  1 kvm
snd_hda_codec         135168  4 snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec_analog
drm_kms_helper        180224  1 i915
input_leds             16384  0
ecdh_generic           28672  1 bluetooth
snd_hda_core           86016  5 snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec_analog,snd_hda_codec
drm                   483328  4 drm_kms_helper,i915
snd_hwdep              20480  1 snd_hda_codec
i2c_algo_bit           16384  1 i915
serio_raw              20480  0
fb_sys_fops            16384  1 drm_kms_helper
snd_pcm               102400  4 snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_core
lpc_ich                24576  0
snd_timer              36864  1 snd_pcm
syscopyarea            16384  1 drm_kms_helper
snd                    86016  14 snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hwdep,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec_analog,snd_hda_codec,snd_timer,snd_pcm
soundcore              16384  1 snd
sysfillrect            16384  1 drm_kms_helper
sysimgblt              16384  1 drm_kms_helper
mac_hid                16384  0
sch_fq_codel           20480  2
parport_pc             36864  0
ppdev                  24576  0
lp                     20480  0
parport                53248  3 parport_pc,lp,ppdev
ip_tables              32768  0
x_tables               40960  1 ip_tables
autofs4                45056  2
psmouse               151552  0
ahci                   40960  1
libahci                32768  1 ahci
pata_acpi              16384  0
wmi                    28672  2 hp_wmi,wmi_bmof
video                  49152  1 i915
e1000e                245760  0

rfkll list all: 0: hp-wifi: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: hp-bluetooth: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
3: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
4: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no

sudo dmesg | grep iwl: [   16.501717] iwl3945: Intel(R) PRO/Wireless 3945ABG/BG Network Connection driver for Linux, in-tree:s
[   16.501718] iwl3945: Copyright(c) 2003-2011 Intel Corporation
[   16.501725] iwl3945: hw_scan is disabled
[   16.501804] iwl3945 0000:10:00.0: can't disable ASPM; OS doesn't have ASPM control
[   16.557822] iwl3945 0000:10:00.0: Tunable channels: 13 802.11bg, 23 802.11a channels
[   16.557825] iwl3945 0000:10:00.0: Detected Intel Wireless WiFi Link 3945ABG
[   16.682640] ieee80211 phy0: Selected rate control algorithm 'iwl-3945-rs'
[   16.686923] iwl3945 0000:10:00.0 wlp16s0: renamed from wlan0
[   27.052989] Modules linked in: bnep i915 arc4 kvmgt iwl3945 vfio_mdev iwlegacy mdev mac80211 vfio_iommu_type1 coretemp vfio cfg80211 snd_hda_codec_hdmi wmi_bmof hp_wmi snd_hda_codec_analog snd_hda_codec_generic kvm btusb sparse_keymap ledtrig_audio btrtl irqbypass snd_hda_intel drm_kms_helper joydev btbcm snd_hda_codec drm btintel i2c_algo_bit snd_hda_core bluetooth fb_sys_fops snd_hwdep input_leds ecdh_generic snd_pcm snd_timer syscopyarea serio_raw snd lpc_ich soundcore sysfillrect sysimgblt mac_hid sch_fq_codel parport_pc ppdev lp parport ip_tables x_tables autofs4 psmouse ahci libahci pata_acpi wmi video e1000e
[   58.545175] Modules linked in: bnep i915 arc4 kvmgt iwl3945 vfio_mdev iwlegacy mdev mac80211 vfio_iommu_type1 coretemp vfio cfg80211 snd_hda_codec_hdmi wmi_bmof hp_wmi snd_hda_codec_analog snd_hda_codec_generic kvm btusb sparse_keymap ledtrig_audio btrtl irqbypass snd_hda_intel drm_kms_helper joydev btbcm snd_hda_codec drm btintel i2c_algo_bit snd_hda_core bluetooth fb_sys_fops snd_hwdep input_leds ecdh_generic snd_pcm snd_timer syscopyarea serio_raw snd lpc_ich soundcore sysfillrect sysimgblt mac_hid sch_fq_codel parport_pc ppdev lp parport ip_tables x_tables autofs4 psmouse ahci libahci pata_acpi wmi video e1000e
[   89.264986] Modules linked in: bnep i915 arc4 kvmgt iwl3945 vfio_mdev iwlegacy mdev mac80211 vfio_iommu_type1 coretemp vfio cfg80211 snd_hda_codec_hdmi wmi_bmof hp_wmi snd_hda_codec_analog snd_hda_codec_generic kvm btusb sparse_keymap ledtrig_audio btrtl irqbypass snd_hda_intel drm_kms_helper joydev btbcm snd_hda_codec drm btintel i2c_algo_bit snd_hda_core bluetooth fb_sys_fops snd_hwdep input_leds ecdh_generic snd_pcm snd_timer syscopyarea serio_raw snd lpc_ich soundcore sysfillrect sysimgblt mac_hid sch_fq_codel parport_pc ppdev lp parport ip_tables x_tables autofs4 psmouse ahci libahci pata_acpi wmi video e1000e
[  121.005068] Modules linked in: bnep i915 arc4 kvmgt iwl3945 vfio_mdev iwlegacy mdev mac80211 vfio_iommu_type1 coretemp vfio cfg80211 snd_hda_codec_hdmi wmi_bmof hp_wmi snd_hda_codec_analog snd_hda_codec_generic kvm btusb sparse_keymap ledtrig_audio btrtl irqbypass snd_hda_intel drm_kms_helper joydev btbcm snd_hda_codec drm btintel i2c_algo_bit snd_hda_core bluetooth fb_sys_fops snd_hwdep input_leds ecdh_generic snd_pcm snd_timer syscopyarea serio_raw snd lpc_ich soundcore sysfillrect sysimgblt mac_hid sch_fq_codel parport_pc ppdev lp parport ip_tables x_tables autofs4 psmouse ahci libahci pata_acpi wmi video e1000e
[  151.725047] Modules linked in: bnep i915 arc4 kvmgt iwl3945 vfio_mdev iwlegacy mdev mac80211 vfio_iommu_type1 coretemp vfio cfg80211 snd_hda_codec_hdmi wmi_bmof hp_wmi snd_hda_codec_analog snd_hda_codec_generic kvm btusb sparse_keymap ledtrig_audio btrtl irqbypass snd_hda_intel drm_kms_helper joydev btbcm snd_hda_codec drm btintel i2c_algo_bit snd_hda_core bluetooth fb_sys_fops snd_hwdep input_leds ecdh_generic snd_pcm snd_timer syscopyarea serio_raw snd lpc_ich soundcore sysfillrect sysimgblt mac_hid sch_fq_codel parport_pc ppdev lp parport ip_tables x_tables autofs4 psmouse ahci libahci pata_acpi wmi video e1000e
```

Comment: There is no special procedure to enable this wifi module in Lubuntu. Most probably, you need to look for a physical, probably plastic switch or button to turn on wifi.

Comment: I've tried to turn on the witi external button, but it doesn't work

Comment: Please edit your question to show the result of the terminal commands: `rfkill list all` and also: `lsmod`  Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: rfkll list all: 0: hp-wifi: Wireless LAN
 Soft blocked: no
 Hard blocked: no
1: hp-bluetooth: Bluetooth
 Soft blocked: no
 Hard blocked: no
3: phy0: Wireless LAN
 Soft blocked: no
 Hard blocked: no
4: hci0: Bluetooth
 Soft blocked: no
 Hard blocked: no

Comment: Please add output of `dmesg | grep iwl` to your question.

Comment: All looks well to me. Wi-Fi should work.

Comment: ok i added to the  question

Comment: still does not detect networks

Comment: what to do to sense

Comment: No soft- or hard-blocks; good so far. Please run: `dmesg | grep -e iwl -e wlp` As the result may be lengthy, please post the result here and give us the link: http://paste.ubuntu.com

Comment: https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/x6shDvKYFn/

Comment: here is the link

Comment: So far, as Pilot6 says, we see *nothing* wrong, except it doesn't work. Let's also see a paste of: `dmesg | grep 10:00`

Comment: here is the link https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/JHcytKN6gM/

Comment: We still see nothing wrong and therefore fixable. Please run: `sudo lshw -C netwrork` and then press the wireless button or key combination. Run again: `sudo lshw -C network` Is there any change in the DISABLED indication?